# How do you compile Java+Kotlin project using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, kotlin

I'm trying to compile maven project which has Kotlin classes referencing Java classes. Here's a part of my parent POM:

```
...

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
</dependency>

...

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${compiler-plugin-version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${java-version}</source>
        <target>${java-version}</target>
        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <version>${kotlin.plugin.version}</version>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>test-compile</id>
            <phase>process-test-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>

    <configuration>
        <scanForAnnotations>false</scanForAnnotations>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And related parts of the child POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
</dependency>

...

<plugin>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <configuration>
        <sourceDirs>
            <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</source>
        </sourceDirs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And the Kotlin class:

```
Stateless
open class DummyServiceImpl : DummyService {

    PersistenceContext(unitName = Consts.UNIT_NAME)
    private val em: EntityManager? = null

    override fun get(id: Long?): Dummy {
        return em!!.find<Dummy>(javaClass<Dummy>(), id)
    }

    override fun sayHi(): String {
        return "Dummy service says \"Hi!\"."
    }
}
```

`DummyService` and `Consts` classes are Java classes residing in the same module as `DummyServiceImpl`.
So when I compile the module containing `DummyServiceImpl` with Maven it goes like this:

```
[error] C:\somepath\service\DummyServiceImpl.kt: (14, 31) Unresolved reference: DummyService
[error] C:\somepath\service\DummyServiceImpl.kt: (16, 35) Unresolved reference: Consts
```

If I switch Kotlin plugin execution `phase` to `compile` then it predictably fails if there're references from Java to Kotlin classes:

```
[ERROR] /C:/somepath/service/impl/DummyServiceClientImpl.java:[5,27] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class DummyServiceImpl
```

So, what's to be done about this? Note that building with IDEA's `make` goes perfectly fine.

Comment: Is your Java code in different module?

Comment: @SergeyMashkov Nope, same module.

Comment: I encountered the same problem in gradle. Have you found any solution yet?

Comment: @DANGFan nope, sorry.

Comment: what if I have a Kotlin-only project and want to use maven for it (so that dependencies can be specified in the pom), do I just use a pom.xml ?

Comment: As of 2017: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052965/mixed-kotlin-java-with-maven-unresolved-reference

Comment: @Marit this question is almost 3 years old already. So no, it's not duplicate.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Make sure you have this declaration in `<build>` of your pom.xml

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <source>src/main/java</source>
                            <source>src/main/kotlin</source>
                            <source>src/main/resources</source>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>process-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <source>src/test/java</source>
                            <source>src/test/kotlin</source>
                            <source>src/test/resources</source>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Make sure that **all folders** (3x in src/main & 3x in src/test) mentioned in the configuration **actually** exist, even if they don’t contain any classes/resources. You can still fine-tune the configuration once it works for you.

Also pay attention to use exactly the same order I mentioned above to let the compiler compile the Java code first.

Comment: What's the difference to not mentioning the sourceDirs explicitly (e.g. as in the official manual? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html)

Comment: @LukasEder I posted this configuration as it is proven to work. As I posted this configuration I’ve used a pre-beta version of Kotlin and its Maven plugin. So it might be that it got more resilient now and infers stuff that it did not before.

Answer (score 8):

Referred from this [Kotlin + java demo apps](https://github.com/webfirmframework/kotlin-wffweb-demo-apps/blob/master/kotlinminimalproductionsample/pom.xml)

You have to execute `mvn kotlin:compile` before `mvn package`. `mvn kotlin:compile` will compile the *Kotlin* files to class files.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.wffweb</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlinminimalproductionsample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <!--
    To package as war:- mvn clean kotlin:compile package
    -->

    <properties>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMddHHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <kotlin.version>1.2.21</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.webfirmframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>wffweb</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 4):

I ended using the following configuration to mix Java and Kotlin source code:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <source>src/main/kotlin</source>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <source>src/test/kotlin</source>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to **NOT** use the build options: **sourceDirectory** and **testSourceDirectory**

[image: pom.xml example]

All configurations goes at kotlin-maven-plugin, for more accurate information see:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/maven.html#compile-kotlin-and-java-sources