# Mixed Kotlin + Java with Maven, unresolved reference

Tags: java, maven, interop, kotlin

I have a Maven project with Kotlin code `hello.kt` which calls Java code `JavaFoo.java` which calls Kotlin code `KotlinFoo.kt`. `hello.kt` also calls `KotlinFoo.kt` directly. I'm trying to build this with `mvn clean install` using exactly the Maven settings described in [kotlinlang's Maven docs](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html#compiling-kotlin-and-java-sources).

If `hello.kt` doesn't call `JavaFoo` (but I leave `JavaFoo` in the project) then this builds just fine.

The docs say that the Kotlin compiler should be invoked before the Java compiler, which suggests to me that all Kotlin code needs to compile before any Java code, i.e. with this setup you can call Kotlin from Java but not vice versa.  However, the docs describe this setup as just "mixed code applications", not "calling Kotlin from Java".

In other words, this failure seems consistent with what the docs seem to imply but not with what they directly say -- or I'm just misunderstanding something.

I want to call each language from the other. Is there a Maven configuration that will do this, please?

(I looked at various StackExchange questions on mixed code settings and none of the solutions works for me.)

Adding the code as requested:
pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.kotlindemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-demo</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>kotlin-demo</name>

    <properties>
        <kotlin.version>1.1.2-2</kotlin.version> 
        <kotlin.compiler.incremental>true</kotlin.compiler.incremental>
        <main.class>com.example.kotlindemo.HelloKt</main.class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals> <goal>compile</goal> </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals> <goal>test-compile</goal> </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Replacing default-compile as it is treated specially by maven -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Replacing default-testCompile as it is treated specially by maven -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-testCompile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>java-compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals> <goal>compile</goal> </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>java-test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals> <goal>testCompile</goal> </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals> <goal>single</goal> </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

`src/main/kotlin/hello.kt`:

```
package com.example.kotlindemo

fun main(args : Array<String>) { 
  println("Hello, world!") 

  var kfoo = KotlinFoo()
  kfoo.printFooString()

  kfoo.fooString = "init2"
  kfoo.printFooString()

  var foo2 = JavaFoo("abcd")
  foo2.printString()
}
```

`src/main/kotlin/KotlinFoo.kt`:

```
package com.example.kotlindemo

class KotlinFoo {
    var fooString = "init"

    fun printFooString() {
        println(this.fooString) 
    }
}
```

`src/main/java/JavaFoo.java`:

```
package com.example.kotlindemo;

class JavaFoo {
    private KotlinFoo k;

    JavaFoo(String initializer) {
        k = new KotlinFoo();
        k.setFooString(initializer);
    }

    void printString() {
        this.k.printFooString();
    }
}
```

Error:

```
[ERROR] .../src/main/kotlin/hello.kt: (12, 14) Unresolved reference: JavaFoo
```

Comment: Can you add the code to your question? I think it will help us understand the situation a bit better. I'm pretty sure you can call kotlin and java in both directions I understand this link correctly https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330311/how-do-you-compile-javakotlin-project-using-maven

Comment: @guenhter I looked at all stackoverflow posts on this that I could find (including the one you linked to). None of those suggestions helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compilation fails because your Java class is not in a directory that matches its package statement. While Kotlin allows you to put classes in any directories regardless of the package they're in, Java requires you to put each file in a package that corresponds to its directory. This requirement applies to mixed-language projects as well.

To fix the error, move `JavaFoo.java` to `src/main/java/com/example/kotlindemo`.

Comment: This is **not true**. You can put Java files anywhere you like. It's only a convention to put it in a path matching the package.

Comment: That was it, thanks!

@tynn, it could be a maven requirement, perhaps?

Comment: @tynn for the Kotlin compiler to be able to read Java files, it's definitely a requirement

Comment: @user747267 it's not related to Maven. The same happens with Gradle. But your guess was right. Kotlin runs before Java. I'd guess that Kotlin is actually only looking for sources and thus requires the right package. Maybe it would be better to say: _Kotlin requires you to put each Java file in ..._

Comment: @tynn, you actually *do* have to have the compiled java code in the correct package location in order to access it (unless you are doing tricks with symlinks or fake classpath structures). You can *compile* it anywhere outside of the package location but if something is trying to read/use it, it must be in the correct package location.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven, you need to add the goal: `<goal>addSources</goal>`

Like this:

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>addSources</goal>
            <goal>addTestSources</goal>
            <goal>generateStubs</goal>
            <goal>compile</goal>
            <goal>testGenerateStubs</goal>
            <goal>testCompile</goal>
            <goal>removeStubs</goal>
            <goal>removeTestStubs</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```