# Kotlin folder not detecting as source folder in Maven eclipse, sts

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, kotlin, spring-tool-suite

[image]

As you can see in the image, I have created a folder `koltin`in the main folder and also set the source directory to that folder in the `pom.xml`. But still kotlin is not detecting as source folder. As you can see in the top of this project. other source folders are detecting fine.

1. src/main/java
2. src/main/resources
3. src/test/java
4. src/test/resources
5. src/main/kotlin ------> this is missing, it should be here.

POM.XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.climesoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenkotlin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <properties>
        <kotlin.version>1.2.61</kotlin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <source>src/main/java</source>
                                <source>src/main/kotlin</source>
                                <source>src/main/resources</source>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>process-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <source>src/test/java</source>
                                <source>src/test/resources</source>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.jetbrains.kotlin
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            kotlin-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.2.61,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you compile Java+Kotlin project using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330311/how-do-you-compile-javakotlin-project-using-maven)

Comment: @C.Champagne I'm talking about why eclipse/sts not detecting kotlin folder as it detects java folder?

Comment: Yes sorry, I should have given a small comment as explanation. It is because it is a Maven project and the sources are by convention src/main,/java src/test/java...but not src/main/kotlin/. If you require an additional source folder, you have to configure it in you pom file. That said Eclipse could do it.

Comment: @C.Champagne I had already configured. But still not detecting. Let me show you my pom.xml

Comment: Have you tought about splitting your module into two?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding below plugin to your pom file. Note that same can be done for test-compile to show `src/test/kotlin`.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirs>
                    <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                    <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
                </sourceDirs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Nothing happened, still same.

Comment: @AsifMushtaq Just a silly question : have you clicked on update Maven project?

Comment: Yes a lot of time.