# Kotlin/Java circular dependencies in maven project

Tags: kotlin, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

So I am trying to add Kotlin into an existing Java project. I have done this before in a project built with Gradle and no issues but it seems to be a bit harder with Maven. Specifically, with circular dependencies. It seems that I can refer to Kotlin classes in Java but not the reverse (unless perhaps I compiled them in the other order).

The build section of my pom.xml is as follows:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>kapt</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>kapt</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <annotationProcessorPath>
                                <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
                                <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
                                <version>2.9</version>
                            </annotationProcessorPath>
                            <annotationProcessorPath>
                                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                                <version>1.18.22</version>
                            </annotationProcessorPath>
                        </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/kotlin</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <jvmTarget>17</jvmTarget>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>java-compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>java-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and I am getting the following build error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.9.22:test-compile (test-compile) on project commons-integration-all: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /Users/jkramer/source/commons/commons-parent/commons-integration-all/src/test/kotlin/com/commons/integration/integr/client/KotlinIntegrClientTest.kt:[4,68] Unresolved reference: IntegrResponseDeserializerTest
```

Now this is in the test but I strongly suspect I would see something similar in the main path if I had such a dependency (which I don't yet).

Any ways to address this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you compile Java+Kotlin project using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330311/how-do-you-compile-javakotlin-project-using-maven)